# Raphael js drag inside javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, raphael, drag

I had a little problem today and thought I could try stack overflow. I'll be short and sweet (I removed lot of code to make this clear).

I recently discovered raphaeljs and I like it.
I make some circle draggable and it works fine like this:

Working script:

```
<script>
var paper = Raphael(100,100,500,500);
var circ = paper.circle(50,50,10)

var start = function(){ };
var move = function(dx,dy)
{
    this.attr({cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy});
};
var up = function(){};
circ.drag(move,start,up);
<script>
```

Ok fine, it works and all functions are called properly! 
BUT!
I want my move ,start ,up functions to be inside an object and not in the main page 
SO 
here's my next code

```
<script src="myobject.js"></script>
<script>
    var paper = Raphael(100,100,500,500);
    var myobj = new myobject("12","12","6");
<script>
```

Content of myobject.js :

```
function myobject(vx,vy,vr)
{
    var x,y,r;
    x=vx;y=vy;r=vr
    paper.circle(x,y,r);    
    var start = function(){};
    var move = function(dx,dy){};
    var up = function(){};

    this.drag(move,start,up);  // error here this line crash

}
```

**I cannot find how to use the drag function inside my object to make it draggable.**

Well, that's it. I hope I've been clear and pardon me if there's anything wrong with the way I made this post but it is my first one!

Thanks to everyone that will try to help me!

Wilson

Comment: Can you make http://jsfiddle.net/ with working and not working version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `myobject`, `this` variable points to this object, and not to Raphael circle. As `myobject` does not have `drag` function, the code yields an error. To make it work, you must refer to Raphael object that has to be dragged, i.e.

```
function myobject(vx,vy,vr) {
    ...
    this.circle = paper.circle(x,y,r);    
    ...
    this.circle.drag(move,start,up);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fine, @Hubert OG was right but I also had to change the way I declared my function from

var start()=function
to
this.start() = function

WARNING: Fill your circle/forms because if you don't you have to click the fine border to move it around.